# How to Print PriorityQueue with Custom Object in Java

Tags: java, queue, comparator, priority-queue

I want to print PriorityQueue of custom object. But when i see any official docs and tutorial, i have to use poll method. Is there any way i can print without removing the element? Here is my code:

**Data class:**

```
class Mhswa {

    String nama;
    int thnMasuk;

    public Mhswa(String nama, int thnMasuk) {
        this.nama = nama;
        this.thnMasuk = thnMasuk;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }
}
```

**Comparator class:**

```
class MhswaCompare implements Comparator<Mhswa> {
    public int compare(Mhswa s1, Mhswa s2) {
        if (s1.thnMasuk < s2.thnMasuk)
            return -1;
        else if (s1.thnMasuk > s2.thnMasuk)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Mhswa> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(5, new MhswaCompare());
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Sandman", 2019));
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Ironman", 2020));
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Iceman", 2021));
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Landman", 2018));
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Wingman", 2010));
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Catman", 2019));
        pq.add(new Mhswa("Speedman", 2015));

        int i = 0;
        // the print section that have to use poll()
        while (!pq.isEmpty()) { 
            System.out.println("Data ke " + i + " : " + pq.peek().nama + " " + pq.peek().thnMasuk);
            pq.poll();
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Iterator since PriorityQueue implements Iterable:

```
Iterator it = pq.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) { 
    Mhswa value = it.next();
    System.out.println("Data ke " + i + " : " + value.nama + " " + value.thnMasuk);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Is there any workaround so i dont have to use poll() method, i want to add pq.remove() below the print section, but of course i can not do that since all the item have been remove using poll()

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the example. You don't need poll at all if the only purpose of the queue is to print its contents.

Comment: I want to print in ascending order like "2010, 2015, 2018, ...", If i use the default PriorityQueue order it would be "2010, 2018, 2015, ..." I know that is how PriorityQueue works and that makes the performance good. So, is there any chance to override the compareTo method so that it could achieve the ascending order without needing to poll the element?

Comment: You can convert the PQ to a list using Apache CollectionUtils and print that from the end. If the purpose of the PQ is to sort the objects, it might be a better idea to directly sort the list and not use the PQ.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation, i just curious if there is any way to override the default priority.